# SQL Return to front end

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure and when this is called by the front end code it returns the return value which is 0 instead of select of  total count. can any one tell me what changes do i need to do to make it return the select values instead of return value

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[getTotalSent1] 
(
   @vendorworksationID uniqueidentifier  ,
   @sdate date,
   @edate date
)
as 
begin
   select  
       camp.totalSent + bcamp.totalSent as totalSent 
   from 
       (select   
           COUNT(*) as totalSent  
        from 
           AdvertisedCampaignHistory a  
        where 
           CAST(a.CreationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@sdate as DATE) AND CAST(@edate as DATE)   
           and a.CampaignID in (select cc.CampaignID 
                                from campaign cc, VendorWorkStation vw 
                                where cc.VendorWorkStationID = vw.VendorWorkStationID 
                                  and VendorID = @vendorworksationID))  as camp
   join 
       (select   
            COUNT(*) as totalSent  
        from  
            AdvertisedCampaignHistory a  
        where 
            CAST(a.CreationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@sdate as DATE) AND CAST(@edate as DATE)
            and a.CampaignID in (select bc.BCampaignID 
                                 from BeaconCampaign bc, VendorWorkStation vw 
                                 where bc.VendorWorkStationID = vw.VendorWorkStationID 
                                   and VendorID = @vendorworksationID)) as bcamp on 1=1
  end
```

Output:

```
Totalsent
---------
240

return 
-----
0
```

It's returning 0, I want total sent value

Comment: Declare an output variable: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108(v=sql.110).aspx or write it as a function instead of a procedure (best approach here in my opinion).  0 is the number of rows effected (which is 0 given no insert,update or delete here.) Functions don't change data, procedures do, views simply select data.  So if this could be used elsewhere in code, function seems to make more sense, otherwise a view could work as well...

Comment: Why are you doing this `CAST` ??? `CAST(@sdate as DATE)` - `@sdate` *already* is a `DATE` - no point in casting it *again*!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: if you are calling the stored procedure from a .net program you can consider the usage of the ExecuteScalar method. This method returns a single value from a resultset (one column, one row). Actually you're returning a scalar by definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTotalSent1
AS
DECLARE @TotalSent int

-- Do some work here

SELECT @TotalSent = 240 
RETURN @TotalSent
GO

-- EXEC CODE
DECLARE @totalsent int
EXEC @totalsent = dbo.getTotalSent1
SELECT @totalsent as totalSent
```

Comment: I am not still able to do it

Comment: Do it...as change your code to work like mine? Mine returns value via RETURN code, as you indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[getTotalSent1] 
    (
       @vendorworksationID uniqueidentifier  ,
       @sdate date,
       @edate date

       @total_set int output
    )
    as 
    `enter code here`

   return
```

get param like this

```
   declare @got_it int
    exec [dbo].[getTotalSent1] xxx,yyy,@total_set=@got_it output
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER procedure [dbo].[getTotalSent1] 
    (
       @vendorworksationID uniqueidentifier  ,
       @sdate date,
       @edate date
    )
    as 
    begin
    DECLARE @totalSent INT
       select  
           @totalSent =camp.totalSent + bcamp.totalSent 
       from 
           (select   
               COUNT(*) as totalSent  
            from 
               AdvertisedCampaignHistory a  
            where 
               CAST(a.CreationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@sdate as DATE) AND CAST(@edate as DATE)   
               and a.CampaignID in (select cc.CampaignID 
                                    from campaign cc, VendorWorkStation vw 
                                    where cc.VendorWorkStationID = vw.VendorWorkStationID 
                                      and VendorID = @vendorworksationID))  as camp
       join 
           (select   
                COUNT(*) as totalSent  
            from  
                AdvertisedCampaignHistory a  
            where 
                CAST(a.CreationDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@sdate as DATE) AND CAST(@edate as DATE)
                and a.CampaignID in (select bc.BCampaignID 
                                     from BeaconCampaign bc, VendorWorkStation vw 
                                     where bc.VendorWorkStationID = vw.VendorWorkStationID 
                                       and VendorID = @vendorworksationID)) as bcamp on 1=1

    return @totalSent 
      end
```

Comment: proc does not return param like that-you ned output param.

Answer (score 0):

After `BEGIN` type `SET NOCOUNT ON`;

This disables the default return value for stored procedures, so that you get the results of your query instead.

And as a side note, you **need** to replace your proprietary joins with the ANSI equivalent...

e.g. 
...

```
FROM tblA a
JOIN tblB b
ON   a.key = b.key
```

It's better to avoid doing the join in the WHERE clause.